# how to use srand() in order to create random dots?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I have written a program which is supposed to draw a rectangle and create some random dots in that rectangle. user will define the width of rectangle(as X), and length(as Y) and also number of dots he/she want to create in the rectangle(as n). I have a problem in creating the dots, I use srand for creating random dots, but it creates dots less than it is supposed to. for example if n=3 it creates 2dots. I haven't used srand before.
here is the code that causes the problem:

```
void create_mines(int x,int n)
{
    int i, random;

    srand(time(0));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        random = rand() % (x);
        board[random][i] = '*';
    }

}
```

what's wrong?

Comment: You should try printing out the value of `random` at each step to see if you're getting a collision.  "Random" does _not_ mean uniformly distributed.  If you want to have exactly `n` distinct points, you might consider pre-filling the board with `n` points and then using a _shuffle algorithm_ to redistribute them.

Comment: if the `random` value is outside the range of 0...(x-1) then the program will have undefined behaviour.   If the `n` value is outside the range of 0...(y-1) then the program will have undefined behaviour.   Suggest: 1) add code to check the limits 2) use another call to `rand()` rather than using `i` to index into the array.  3) pass the `y` value as a parameter to the function.  4) `random` is a well known function name that was brought into the code (along with the `srand()` and `rand()` function) with the `#include <stdlib.h>` statement so should not be used as a variable name.

Comment: How can `rand() % (x)` fall outside 0..x-1 ?  Isn't that pretty much the definition of modulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you need to consider is the possibility that you will try to dot the same spot more than once, thus "losing" a dot.

You should check if a spot is already dotted and try again.

Also you should make sure they don't ask for more dots than is possible.

I would also move the call to srand() out if this function - normally you want to insure your program only does it one time.

```
void create_mines(int x, int n) {   /* THIS VERSION BROKEN, SEE BELOW */
    int i;
    int r;

    if (n > x) return;  /* not possible */

    /* do srand() in main */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        do {
            r = rand() % (x);
        } while (board[r][i] == '*');
        board[r][i] = '*';
    }
}
```

Your program (and my modification above) fail if `n > y` because then

```
board[r][i] = '*';
```

is outside the array (`i` is too large).  Revised code:

```
void create_mines(int x, int y, int n) {
    int i;
    int rx;
    int ry;

    if (n > (x * y)) return;  /* more dots than spots for them */

    /* do srand() in main */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        do {
            rx = rand() % x;
            ry = rand() % y;
        } while (board[rx][ry] == '*');
        board[rx][ry] = '*';
    }
}
```

If `x`*`y` and `n` are **large** then this method is inefficient and a shuffle approach (as suggested in comments above) may be a better approach.

Comment: how should I prevent this situation?

Comment: there are multiple way to prevent it, one possibility is just brute forcing it, sort of `if (board[random][i] == '*') { --i; continue; }`.

Comment: Do you call create_mines() more than once?

Comment: No I just call it one time

Comment: Then the srand thing is less important

Comment: the OPs posted program will not have any overlaps as the `y` value is being incremented (the `i` variable) so there will be no duplicate positions.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I asked if `create_mines()` was called more than once (esp since it would very likely get the same seed for `srand()`).

Comment: But given that it is only called once, I am somewhat perplexed.

Comment: Ah, if `n` is too large, then `i` gets too large and we are outside the array.